# Transfer paid app to Huawei device

Tags: huawei

I've purchased VerbTeX Pro for my Android tablet and recently I upgraded to the MatePad Pro. I'm wondering is there any way to extract the APK and install it on the MatePad without installing GMS?

Comment: In general, when you purchase an app through the Play Store, it is tied to your Google account and not a specific device or installation. The APK files for a paid vs free version are generally also the same and they are just enabled on the Google account. If you paid for the app and installed it on a new device and it doesn't have the paid features, look in the settings of the app for "Enable paid features" or something like that, otherwise message the developer.

Comment: why not ask [Trump](https://mobile.twitter.com/realdonaldtrump) directly